# Openstack Neutron Linux Bridge MTU 1500 issue

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

We have configured Neutron and ml2 agent to use MTU 1500 using linux bridge agent but the VM's cannot run apt update but if we set the MTU to 1450 in the VM network interface works well.

Here is my neutron.conf value and ml2_conf.ini.

neutron.conf:

global_physnet_mtu = 1550

ml2_conf.ini:

[DEFAULT]

path_mtu = 1550

physical_network_mtus = physnet1:1550

Vxlan:

+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                     | Value                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up            | UP                                   |
| availability_zone_hints   |                                      |
| availability_zones        | nova                                 |
| created_at                | 2021-03-30T17:40:59Z                 |
| description               |                                      |
| dns_domain                | None                                 |
| id                        | 4ddce1ef-8151-4c67-b3ca-7519f2ab54c3 |
| ipv4_address_scope        | None                                 |
| ipv6_address_scope        | None                                 |
| is_default                | None                                 |
| is_vlan_transparent       | None                                 |
| mtu                       | 1500                                 |
| name                      | gfgfggf                              |
| port_security_enabled     | True                                 |
| project_id                | 2467cb8a053d40f0a0a8af43d89d1c32     |
| provider:network_type     | vxlan                                |
| provider:physical_network | None                                 |
| provider:segmentation_id  | 2                                    |
| qos_policy_id             | None                                 |
| revision_number           | 4                                    |
| router:external           | Internal                             |
| segments                  | None                                 |
| shared                    | False                                |
| status                    | ACTIVE                               |
| subnets                   | 9a312e58-e830-4dc5-bd6e-ad903230f6b4 |
| tags                      |                                      |
| updated_at                | 2021-03-30T17:57:31Z                 |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+

Anyone can help?

UPDATE: The issue was solved restarting the controller and all hypervisors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The settings in ml2_conf.ini should be under the heading `[ml2]`. `[DEFAULT]` is used in neutron.conf.

Comment: Hi @bakakuna, yes, the configuration it is in both sections. The issue was solved restarting the controller and all hypervisors.